# Databases with Windows phone SDK version 7.0

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, sqlite, sql-server-ce

I am working on a Windows phone7 application and need to store some information in a lightweight relational database(Like SQLite DB in Android and Iphone).

I searched and found SQL CE, but realized that it only works with windows phone OS version 7.1 if I am correct. Since my target version is windows phone OS 7.0, Will I have to Use any 3rd party Database?

Will be really gratefull if someone can suggest the best working solution with experience and any reference/ Good tutorial or any idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://blog.activa.be/index.php/2011/04/using-sqlite-in-a-windows-phone-app/ for example.

Comment: Out of interest why are you targetting 7.0? All existing generation 1 devices have had upgrades to 7.1 and all new devices created will be 7.1, therefore why not target 7.1 from the outset?

Comment: Why 7.0 - all current Windows Phones support 7.1 ?

Comment: @ Paul Diston & ErikEJ --> Both of you mean that targeting OS version 7.0 is useless. That means is it free to update it to OS version 7.1 for the devices which came with OS version 7.0. If so then it's true targetting the OS version 7.0 is completely Useless because the Mango version Have come up with a great enhancement. Is it?

Comment: Windows Phone 7.5 required to download from Marketplace : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/Starting-today-you-need-Windows-Phone-7-5-to-use-Marketplace#.T7yWkdh7urk.twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have database support in Windows Phone by using Linq to SQL; please check "Local Database Sample" in the [Windows Phone Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for a good demo on how to use it.

Comment: Hi Pedro Lamas. Yes the problem is My target OS version is Winsows phone OS 7.0 and not 7.1. Therefore I guess SQL CE is not working with target version 7.0 to work with. In one of the above suggestions in the comments "Paul Diston"  have suggested to select target version 7.1. If I do so then I can go to your solution. but again I am not sure all the windows phone OS 7.0 Users can Upgrade the OS for 7.1 for free. If it is the case, then its good to select the target version to 7.1. Otherwise the devices came up with Windows phone 7.0 will not be able to install this. Thanks

Comment: My friend, **all** Windows Phone 7.0 devices can (**and should**) be upgraded freely to 7.5 OS (the SDK is 7.1 in this case), so you should really be using the 7.1 SDK